# Loading Twitter feeds on Java website

Tags: java, twitter

I am working on a project which consists of requirements for showing organization's twitter feeds on intranet which is a java based application.

I have a Javascript widget provided by Twitter but due to some issues, it might not work well. So I thought of implementing on server side which would give me better control. I have seen Spring social framework as well as twitter4j framework.

If anyone of you has previously worked with similar task, could you please suggest me the simplest and good Java API for implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd use the Google Feeds API in JavaScript on the client to generate HTML from the feed. Then it'll work with other RSS feeds. (e.g. https://wansdyke-house.co.uk )

You can use a similar principle with a little more control by using a Java RSS library such as [Rome](http://rometools.org/).

Comment: Actually the problem is, this is to be used within the organization. As we know PCs within the organization connect to external world through PROXY and I am worried about rate limit getting crossed in this case. That's why I am looking for server side code sothat I can control how many times it connects to the API.

Comment: Understood. Edited the answer slightly to offer another suggestion.